# One son used other sons gmail account

Tags: pokemon-go

My oldest son used my younger son's gmail account to creat his Pokemon go account. Now when my younger son logs into his Pokemon go account it automatically go to the new account that my older son created. Is there anything we can do to resolve this problem?

Comment: There's a decent chance that you can get in touch with Niantic customer support and ask them to change the email address on the account. I suspect that's the kind of thing that is very easy for customer support to fix. :) https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Just a few things for you to also check out. I hope I don't sound too negative!
Have you also asked your older son why he did that? If he doesn't have an email account of his own have him create one. You want to make sure that he didn't create two accounts because he was banned or was cheating on another account. Also make sure that they aren't making purchases you don't want them to within the app.
Make sure your younger son changes his email password so it wont happen again and it's a good lesson for him to learn to not share your passwords. Hopefully your older son didn't use that email for anything else as many things require an email address to log in or create accounts. Sorry to sound too negative.
Good luck!